# Build Tensorflow version2.5 from the source with OpenMP support

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow2.0, bazel

I want to build Tensorflow version 2.5 from the source with OpenMP support enabled? How can I build tensorflow2.5 from the source with OpenMP support enabled?

Comment: The [tensorflow documentation](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/source) describes in detail how to build from source. Build with [MKL](https://software.intel.com/content/www/us/en/develop/articles/guide-to-tensorflow-runtime-optimizations-for-cpu.html) support.

Comment: @gobrewers14, It is okay, But from the tensorflow2.5 version, if we follow TensorFlow documentation, it will use Eigen::ThreadPool. I am asking here what way I need to follow to build the tensorflow2.5 so that it is built with OpenMP support.